# Google Sign-In Websites Ionic 2 Browser - Refused to display frame

Tags: ionic-framework, google-signin, google-oauth, google-plus-signin

I'm trying to implement Google auth for a web app built with Ionic 2.

I'm using [Google Sign-In for Websites](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference)

and implemented as:

```
loginGoogle(referral: any) {
    this.auth2.grantOfflineAccess().then((resp) => {
        var auth_code = resp.code;
    });
}
```

Using `ionic serve`I can sign-in without any issues.
If I deploy it as a `browser` app with `ionic run browser` it doesn't work and shows the following errors:

[image: Errors]

Can anybody tell how to overcome this error.

Thanks